# Google Analytics - Is head match of goal URL any substring of the actual URL

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 urls to be tracked under a single goal :

```
/vpv/purchase_item
/vpv/purchase_coupon
```

So, I have setup a head match as /vpv/purchase.

Is this correct, as **/vpv/purchase** is a substring of both the urls i need to track ?
Or does head match considers the complete URL except the query string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this correct, as /vpv/purchase is a substring of both the urls i need to track?* **Yes**

*Or does head match considers the complete URL except the query string?* **No**

> > A **head match** matches identical characters starting from the beginning of the string up to and including the last character in the string you specify.
> >
> > **Head Match**
> >
> > Suppose your pet store website has a number of pages in a single directory, and you want to use a head match URL to create a goal only for the fish-related pages, which all have the same structure:
> >
> > `/supplies/fishFood.html`
> >
> > `/supplies/fishTanks.html`
> >
> > `/supplies/fishTankDecorations.html`
> >
> > To determine whether your head match URI works, go to the Pages report for your site, click the Search button and choose "Begins with" as your search type. To match the URLs above, you would enter `/supplies/fish` in the search field. If your search returns those pages you expect to match, you can use that same URI string as you goal URL.

See [Verifying Correct URL Expressions for Goals](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1116091#urlMatchTypes)